# JOptionPane Input Dialog during paintComponent in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, binary-tree, joptionpane

I'm using Java in Netbeans to draw a weighted binary tree. on mouseClick event, a node is drawn, and pressing and releasing the mouse in different points on the pane creates an edge, immediately after which i need an input dialog to pop up and ask the user to input the weight of the edge. This is my code. Don't bother going through the entire code, though.

```
public class panel1 extends JPanel implements MouseListener,ActionListener
{

    nodeClass[] nodes = new nodeClass[20];
    int nodeRadius = 10;
    int ctr = 0;
    int[] x=new int[100];    
    int[] y=new int[100];
    int[] oldx=new int[100];
    int[] oldy=new int[100];
    int[] newx=new int[100];
    int[] newy=new int[100];
    int edges=0;
    int[] edgeWeight = new int[100];
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        if(x[ctr]!=0&&y[ctr]!=0)
        {            
            for(int i=0;i<=ctr;i++){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(x[i]-25, y[i]-45, 40, 40);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(i+1),x[i]-10,y[i]-25);

            }    
            for(int i=0;i<edges;i++){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawLine(oldx[i]-10,oldy[i]-30,newx[i]-10,newy[i]-30);
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(edgeWeight[i]), (oldx[i]+newx[i])/2, (oldy[i]+newy[i])/2);
            }
            ctr++;
        }
        if(oldx[edges]!=0&&oldy[edges]!=0&&newx[edges]!=0&&newy[edges]!=0&&(newx[edges]!=oldx[edges] && newy[edges]!=oldy[edges]))
        {
            edgeWeight[edges] = Integer.ParseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Weight Of Edge : "));
            for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(x[i]-25, y[i]-45, 40, 40);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(i+1),x[i]-10,y[i]-25);
            }  
            for(int i=0;i<=edges;i++){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawLine(oldx[i]-10,oldy[i]-30,newx[i]-10,newy[i]-30);
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(edgeWeight[i]), (oldx[i]+newx[i])/2, (oldy[i]+newy[i])/2);
            }
            edges++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        x[ctr]=me.getX();
        y[ctr]=me.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        oldx[edges]=me.getX();
        oldy[edges]=me.getY();    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        newx[edges]=me.getX();
        newy[edges]=me.getY();
        repaint();            
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String str=ae.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(str);
    }  
}
```

The problem arises that, every time i click or drag, an infinite number of JOptionPane input dialogues pop open, and i have no option but to terminate the program.

I haven't put that bit of code under any loop. But maybe it's because it's in the paintComponent method.
Any way to eradicate this problem? Or can i use some other way to get the user to input the weight of the edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem arises that, every time i click or drag, an infinite number of JOptionPane input dialogues pop open

Don't display the JOptionPane dialog in the paintComponent() method. Painting methods are for painting only.

The option pane should be displayed on your mousePressed or mouseReleased code depending on your exact requirement.

Comment: `public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        newx[edges]=me.getX();
        newy[edges]=me.getY();
        edgeWeight[edges] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("EnterWeightOfEdge:"));
        repaint();`

I put that part in the mouseReleased event then.
Now, even if i click the mouse, a JOptionPane shows up. It's not infinite, so it lets me input a value, but now anything i try to do on the panel leads to a JOptionPane. I can't draw anything on it!

Comment: Then maybe you need to change your design. For example maybe you need to use the right mouse button to popup a menu that would contain and option "Add Node". Then that action would display the option pane to get the information you need to draw the node at the point clicked.

Comment: Can i use a textfield?
I mean, whenever i draw an edge, a textfield appears near that node, prompting me to input the weight...
is that feasible?

Comment: How is this different from using a JOptionPane? The text field will still continually popup. Your issue is with the popup, not the component you choose to display.